# Derivate with respect to the ratio of variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have following expression -

$$ \left (\sqrt{y\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)}\right)ax + \left ( \sqrt{1-y\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)}\right)bz $$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants. $y$ is a variable which is a function of fraction $\dfrac{x}{z}$.

I have to derivate the function with respect to ratio of variables, $\dfrac{x}{z}$

I took the $z$ variable out and tried to derivate the following but can't figure out how to handle $\dfrac{1}{z}$ outside the bracket

$$ \frac{1}{z} \left(\sqrt{y\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)}a\frac{x}{z} + \sqrt{1-y\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)}b   \right) $$

Any way out or hint would be helpful.

Comment: I think you can use:
$$\frac{dx}{d(x/z)}=\left(\frac{d(x/z)}{dx}\right)^{-1}=\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-1}=z\\
\frac{dz}{d(x/z)}=\left(\frac{d(x/z)}{dz}\right)^{-1}=\left(-\frac{x}{z^2}\right)^{-1}=-\frac{z^2}{x}$$

Comment: @Feng No one has answered there yet.

Comment: @mohamedshawky Thanks!